# image of "tab" that is not browser's function

Tags: word-meaning

I heard a expression "keep tabs". I could find the meaning by dictionary and also found a meaning of "tab":

> a small flap or strip of material attached to or projecting from
>   something, used to hold, fasten, or manipulate it, or for
>   identification and information.

To my mind comes up with the description only vague image, so I want to see the image itself.
But I couldn't find the image of a "tab", because all google image search result are tabs that is related to computers.

Does anyone know where to find the images of "tabs" in internet?

Comment: FYI that sort of tab *is* the browser function... Check Catija's answer for nice pictures, but the reason we call browser tabs "tabs" is because they look quite a lot like "small flaps or strips of material attached to or projecting from something, used to manipulate it, or for identification and information".

Comment: @akedrou There are lots of real-office references on a computer - think "folders" or "trash"... Good point!

Comment: You wrote [I heard a expression "keep tabs."] followed by a definition for "tab" only. There is a phrase "keep tabs" that has a different meaning, but your question is unclear as to which you are interested in. A full phrase or sentence using the word(s) in question would help to explain the meaning you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are tabs:

They're the little parts of the file folders that are sticking out at the bottom:

[image: Folders with tabs]

Sometimes they are removable and can be filled with slips of paper with what the content is:

[image: File Folder Tabs]

And this is what they look like when they're on the folders:

[image: Tabs for months]